# Pipe B to D? - A && B || C | D

Tags: bash, pipe

Is there a way to re-write the command structure `A && B || C | D` so that either B or C is piped into D?

With the current command either only B or both C and D are run.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, in bash you can use parentheses:

```
(A && B || C) | D
```

This way the output of `A && B || C` will be piped into `D`.

Comment: Or `A && (B || C) | D`, if you don't want B, C, or D to run when A fails

Comment: You can also use parens in `sh` :)

Comment: It's unclear whether using parentheses instead of curly braces was an intentional decision (if so, what are the benefits?) or just an oversight. Could you explain?

Comment: @TomFenech Parens cause the expression to run in a sub-shell, which is a (single) separate process from the POV of the rest of the script. Therefore, whatever the output of the expression inside parens, it will be piped together. (Since `A` is inside the subshell, this also includes `A`.)

Comment: @jpaugh I think your point about isolation is a good one but the output would be piped in the same way when using curly braces, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 15):

You can write this as

```
if A; then B; else C; fi | D
```

You say you want to run either `B` or `C`, but `A && B || C` doesn't achieve that. If `A` succeeds, but `B` runs and fails, it would execute `C`.

Note 1: if you can somehow guarantee that `B` always succeeds and want to stick with a short version, then I'd still opt for

```
{ A && B || C; } | D
```

over `( ... )`, as the latter unnecessarily forces a new subshell to be created, which may or may not get optimised away.

Note 2: both forms assume `A` produces no output, which is true in your example but not necessarily so in general. That can be avoided by

```
A; if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then B; else C; fi | D
```

Comment: Are you sure that `{ … }` does not force a subshell to be created due to the pipe? I observe the following behavior: `pgrep bash` and `pgrep bash | cat` and `if true; then pgrep bash; fi` and `{ pgrep bash; }` have one line of output; `( pgrep bash; )` and `( pgrep bash; ) | cat` and `{ pgrep bash; } | cat` and `if true; then pgrep bash; fi | cat` have two lines of output.

Comment: @wchargin `... | ...` causes a subshell to be created, that's unavoidable. `( ... )`, at least in theory, causes an *additional* subshell to be created that `{ ...; }` avoids, but that's what I meant with "may or may not get optimised away": it's possible that in this particular case, the shell realises it doesn't matter, the effect would be the same.

Answer (score 6):

The accepter answer is correct but it doesn't cover the potential use case to *not* have the output of `A` as the input of `D`. To achieve that you’ll need a stream redirection on `A` depending on your needs.

- If you want to discard the output of `A` anyway:

  ```
  { A >/dev/null && B || C; } | D
  ```
- If you want to see the output of `A` on the terminal:

  ```
  { A >/dev/tty && B || C; } | D
  ```
- If you need the output of `A` as the input of a subsequent command `E` you’ll need an additional command group and stream redirection:

  ```
  { { A >&3 && B || C; } | D; } 3>&1 | E
  ```

---

If all this looks too arcane to you (as it does to me) I recommend that you use the special shell variable for the exit status of `A` and work with that:

```
A
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  B
else
  C
fi |
D
```

If you want to be more concise but not too arcane I suggest this:

```
A; { [ $? -eq 0 ] && B || C; } | D
```

(See also the last part of [hvd’s answer](/a/359502/47852) which I didn't notice when I wrote my original answer.)

Comment: My answer does cover that. See what I put in my "Note 2:", where I simply moved `A` out of the pipeline.

Comment: @hvd: You're correct and thanks for pointing out that part of your answer to me! I altered my claim and gave you credit accordingly.